# Is there a weak maximum principle applicable to this situation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

I am reading a [paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=bethuel&s5=travelling%20waves&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=2461988) and have trouble understanding the following step on page 581:

Assume we know that $w: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and bounded. Furthermore $\Vert w \Vert_{L^\infty}>1$ and $w(x) \to 1$ whenever $\vert x \vert \to \infty.$ Finally the following inequality holds \begin{equation} \Delta w + 2 w(1+\frac{c^2}{4}-w) \geq 0. \end{equation}The author then applys the weak maximum principle to obtain \begin{equation} w \leq 1+\frac{c^2}{4}. \end{equation}

While I found several versions of a "weak maximum principle" (e.g. [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=cacciopoli%20weak%20maximum%20principle&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://people.bath.ac.uk/rm257/MA6000A/notes.pdf&ei=Bo-xUf-HMbKR7AaYqICYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEVvE7hrllLn2sd5uMWAxNzqWzwyg&bvm=bv.47534661,d.ZGU)), I can't figure out how to apply them to this situation. They all either assume that the domain is bounded and/or there are only derivatives of $w$ (but not $w$ itself) in the PDE.

So my question is:

> Can someone give me a hint which version of the weak maximum principle is applicable in this situation and how to apply it?

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: you can't have strictly positive Laplacian at a point of local maximum.

Comment: Aside: not everyone has access to MathSciNet. A direct link to a paper (even if it's behind paywall) is better than a link to a reference to a paper which is itself behind a paywall. The first kind of link at least tells the reader what the paper is, so they can try to find it elsewhere.

Comment: @user79365: the better solution actually is for the OP to copy the link from the "Make link" button on MathSciNet. That link automatically resolves to the MathSciNet review if a subscription is detected, or also to a bibliographic entry that links to the original paper if not. Compare [this link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2461988) with the one provided by the OP. See also [this FAQ item](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/help/getitem.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $w(x)>1+c^2/4$ for some $x$. Since the set $\{x: w(x)\ge 1+c^2/4 \}$ is bounded and closed, it is compact. Let $x_0$ be a point of this set where $w$ attains its maximum. Since it is a global maximum of $w$, we have $w(x_0)>1+c^2/4$.

On the other hand, 
$$\Delta w(x_0)\ge 2w(w-1-c^2/4)>0 \tag1$$
Therefore there is $j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that 
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j^2}w(x_0)>0 \tag2$$
Inequality (2) is incompatible with $w$ (considered as a function of $j$th variable only) having a maximum at $x_0$.